# Angular Lazy Module loaded only after refresh

Tags: angular, angular9

Both on desktop, but more on mobile, when I press on a button:

```html
<button mat-stroked-button [routerLink] = "['/app', 'pages', page.id]"> Details </ button>
```

The route is changed but the module and component are not loaded.
It is loaded only after the refresh.
On dekstop, however, this does not happen many times.

**app-routing.module.ts**

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'welcome', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: 'welcome',
    loadChildren: () => import('./modules/welcome/welcome.module').then((m) => m.WelcomeModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'auth',
    loadChildren: () => import('./modules/auth/auth.module').then((m) => m.AuthModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'app',
    component: MainLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'pages', pathMatch: 'full' },
      {
        path: 'pages',
        loadChildren: () => import('./modules/pages/pages.module').then((m) => m.PagesModule),
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
      },
      {
        path: 'profiles',
        loadChildren: () => import('./modules/profiles/profiles.module').then((m) => m.ProfilesModule),
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    component: PageNotFoundComponent,
  },
];
```

**pages-routing.module.ts**

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: PagesListComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'create',
    component: CreateUpdatePageComponent,
  },
  {
    path: ':id',
    component: PageDetailsComponent,
  },
  {
    path: ':id/update',
    component: CreateUpdatePageComponent,
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class PagesRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score -1):

please try this:

```
<button mat-stroked-button [routerLink] = "['/app/pages/' + page.id]"> Details </ button>
```

In your base routing module you can try to activate debugging:
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {enableTracing: true}),

Comment: I have this worning:
Navigation triggered outside Angular zone, did you forget to call 'ngZone.run()'?

Comment: when? on button click. on startup?

Comment: On button click